# Firebase APN notification are not in the tray when app is in the background

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, ios10, firebase-cloud-messaging

For some reason notifications sent via Firebase don't get in the tray when the app is in the background. Here's the code that initialises Firebase (we're currently testing on iOS 10 using Xamarin in VS 2017). In AppDelegate.cs:

```
    public void InitFirebase()
    {
        // Configure Firebase
        App.Configure();

        // Register your app for remote notifications.
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
        {
            // iOS 10 or later
            var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) =>
            {
                Log.Info("BoaTan", "RequestAuthorization: {0}", granted);
            });

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            Firebase.CloudMessaging.Messaging.SharedInstance.RemoteMessageDelegate = this;
            // Monitor token generation
            InstanceId.Notifications.ObserveTokenRefresh((sender, e) =>
            {
                Log.Info("BoaTan", "New firebase token received {0}", PlatformEntrance.Token);

                LoginViewModel viewModel = LoginView.Me.ViewModel as LoginViewModel;

                viewModel.UpdateFirebaseToken(PlatformEntrance.Token);
            });

            Firebase.CloudMessaging.Messaging.SharedInstance.Connect(error =>
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    Log.Error("BoaTan", error.DebugDescription);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Info("BoaTan", "Connection to Firebase messaging succeeded");
                }
            });

            // Monitor token generation
            InstanceId.Notifications.ObserveTokenRefresh((sender, e) =>
            {
                SendTokenToServer();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // iOS 9 or before
            var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
            var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
        }

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
    }
```

In the AppDelegate.cs we also have the following code to receive the messages:

```
        public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication application)
    {
        Firebase.CloudMessaging.Messaging.SharedInstance.Connect((NSError error) =>
        {
            Log.Info("BoaTan", "WillEnterForeground: Connected to Firebase messaging ({0})", error?.Description);
        });

        base.WillEnterForeground(application);
    }

    public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
    {
        Firebase.CloudMessaging.Messaging.SharedInstance.Disconnect();

        Log.Info("BoaTan", "DidEnterBackground: Disconnected from Firebase messaging");

        base.DidEnterBackground(application);
    }

    // To receive notifications in foregroung on iOS 9 and below.
    // To receive notifications in background in any iOS version
    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        Log.Info("BoaTan", "DidReceiveRemoteNotification: Disconnected from Firebase messaging");

        SendDataMessage(userInfo);
    }

    // To receive notifications in foreground on iOS 10 devices.
    [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        Log.Info("BoaTan", "WillPresentNotification: Disconnected from Firebase messaging");

        SendDataMessage(notification.Request.Content.UserInfo);
    }

    public void ApplicationReceivedRemoteMessage(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        SendDataMessage(message.AppData);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use MvvmCross messaging to send a message to subcribers.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dictionary"></param>
    private void SendDataMessage(NSDictionary dictionary)
    {
        LogReceivedInfo(dictionary);

        NSObject data;
        NSString key = new NSString("data");

        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out data))
        {
            Log.Info("BoaTan", "Data: {0}", data);

            Settings.Notification = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginNotificationParameter>((NSString)data);

            ServicesHelper.SendMessage(this);
        }
    }

    private void LogReceivedInfo(NSDictionary keyvalues)
    {
        Log.Info("BoaTan", "-----------------------------------------------------------");

        foreach (var keyval in keyvalues)
        {
            Log.Info("BoaTan", "Key: {0} Value: {1}", keyval.Key, keyval.Value);
        }

        Log.Info("BoaTan", "-----------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Message arrive perfectly when the App is in the foreground. All messages are queued until the App gets in the Foreground again.

This is in the info.plist:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
</array>
```

When I go to the Firebase console and compose a message there in several variants the messages also don't arrive in the tray which leads me to the following conclusions:

1. The App is missing some configuration telling iOS I'm expecting messages.
2. Something missing is the configuration of APN at the Apple developer console.
3. Something missing in the Firebase/iOS configuration/initialization.

The permutations are endless. Who has the answer? And then there is still the challenge of iOS 9.

Comment: No thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experiences with Firebase on iOS but on Android I had the same problem.
Firebase has two types of messages: `Notification message` and `Data message`, see [About FCM Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)
On Android the `Notification message` is only visible when the app is in foreground. Maybe this is also your problem

Comment: On Android our stuff is working perfectly. In the FCM Message docs it says that Notification messages are delivered into the tray when the app is in the background. That does not happen thought.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly why it started working but it works now. After deleting the App from my iPad and reinstalling it the tray started working too. My guess is that a redeploy keeps setting as they are and after a reinstall these were set correctly.